# How do I run my app on my iPhone with the Beta iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have iOS 12.1 beta on my current iPhone. How am I able to run an app using Xcode on this device? Or will I have to revert back to the original iOS 12 in order to have my iPhone be compatible with Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run your app on iOS 12.1 Beta, you need to use Xcode 10.1 Beta:
https://developer.apple.com/download/